# Given a WSDL file, create a simple Java client

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Can anyone please provide me with a sample code for this? 
I have a wsdl file, and I want to create a client that will call a service from that wsdl file
A working code with some explanation will be really helpful.

I'm using JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main options are to use:

1. [JAX-WS, using the `wsimport` tool](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxwsclientfromwsdl.html).
2. [Apache AXIS2, using `wsdl2java`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#choosingclient).

Both links provide code examples.  Some searching on the web will get you even farther.  There are also options for creating dynamic SOAP clients but the generated ones are easiest.

Comment: Oracle docs on `wsimport`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Answer (score 5):

One of the many possible tools is [`WSDL2Java`](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL). In a shell:

```
$ java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java foo.wsdl
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it from command line using wsimport provided by JAX-WS

wsimport -keep -s (output folder) urlToWsdl

```
> ex : wsimport -keep -s {homeDirectory}/OutputFolder https://www.example.com
```

PS: while using non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
You must specify the "-extension" option to use this binding.

for further reading visit [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/wsimport.html)

Answer (score 3):

NetBeans can generate a lot of that code for you:
File -> New File... -> Web Serices -> Web Service Client

Answer (score 3):

**Eclipse** is having the option to generate java client.
Just Right click on the WSDL file 
Generate Web Service Client 
Thatz all. You get the client to invoke the SOAP Service

Comment: But only if you have the eclipse extensions to handle WSDL files installed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Apache Axis do this automatically. You may want to try that to get to know a little about it.