# wrong java client generated from wsdl

Tags: java-client

i have a wsdl as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Fluidra_WS" targetNamespace="http://www.fluidra.com/Fluidra_WS/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.fluidra.com/Fluidra_WS/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.fluidra.com/Fluidra_WS/">
      <xsd:element name="GetPriceLine">
        <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="CONO" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="FACI" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CUNO" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ITNO" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WHLO" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ORDT" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ORQA" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ALUN" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CUCD" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ORTP" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="PRRF" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DISY" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DWDT" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CFXX" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CAMA" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ATNR" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="PLTB" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CFIN" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="GetPriceLineResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="WHLO" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SAPR" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="LNAM" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ORDT" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ORQA" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ORQS" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="PRRF" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SMCD" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ORTP" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="AAGN" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="BAGN" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DISY" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CUCD" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ALUN" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="PRMO" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SPUN" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SACD" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="PRRO" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CMNO" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIA1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIA2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIA3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIA4" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIA5" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIA6" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIC1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIC2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIC3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIC4" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIC5" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIC6" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CMP1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CMP2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CMP3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CMP4" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CMP5" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CMP6" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="TX81" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="TX82" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="TX83" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="TX84" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="TX85" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="TX86" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CHL1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CHL2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CHL3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CHL4" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CHL5" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="CHL6" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SAC2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="TINC" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="NTCD" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIP1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIP2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIP3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIP4" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIP5" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DIP6" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SAP1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SAP2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SAP3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SAP4" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SAP5" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="SAP6" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DPR1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DPR2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DPR3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DPR4" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DPR5" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="DPR6" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="NETP" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ODAM" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="GetPriceLineRequest">
<wsdl:part element="tns:GetPriceLine" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetPriceLineResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:GetPriceLineResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="Fluidra_WS">
<wsdl:operation name="GetPriceLine">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:GetPriceLineRequest"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:GetPriceLineResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="Fluidra_WSSOAP" type="tns:Fluidra_WS">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPriceLine">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fluidra.com/Fluidra_WS/GetPriceLine"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Fluidra_WS">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:Fluidra_WSSOAP" name="Fluidra_WSSOAP">
  <soap:address location="http://m3mectst:56045/ws/Fluidra_WS"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

when i generate the client from the wsdl using netbeans 7.2 i have a list of classes

- FluidraWS
- FluidraWS_Service
- GetPriceLine
- GetPriceLineResponse
- ObjectFactory
- package-info

When I try to drag the operation to a java class the operation doesn't contain the output object and doesn't have the input object but it is defined as void and the input is a list of simple parameters mixed with input and output

```
// WS from MEC
private static void getPriceLine(java.lang.String cono, java.lang.String    faci, java.lang.String cuno, java.lang.String itno,
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> whlo, javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> ordt, javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> orqa, javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> alun, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> cucd, javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> ortp, javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> 
prrf, javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> disy, java.lang.String dwdt, 
java.lang.String cfxx, java.lang.String cama, java.lang.String atnr,
java.lang.String pltb, java.lang.String cfin,
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sapr,
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> lnam, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> orqs, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> smcd, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> aagn, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> bagn, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> prmo, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> spun, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sacd, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> prro, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> cmno,  
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dia1, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dia2, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dia3, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dia4, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dia5, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dia6, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dic1, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dic2, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dic3, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dic4, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dic5, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dic6, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> cmp1, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> cmp2, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> cmp3, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> cmp4, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> cmp5, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> cmp6, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> tx81, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> tx82, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> tx83, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> tx84, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> tx85, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> tx86, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> chl1, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> chl2, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> chl3, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> chl4, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> chl5, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> chl6, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sac2, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> tinc, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> ntcd, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dip1, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dip2, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dip3, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dip4, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dip5, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dip6, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sap1, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sap2, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sap3, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sap4, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sap5, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sap6, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dpr1, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dpr2, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dpr3, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dpr4, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dpr5, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> dpr6, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> netp, 
javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> odam) {

    com.fluidra.fluidra_ws.FluidraWS_Service service = new com.fluidra.fluidra_ws.FluidraWS_Service();
    com.fluidra.fluidra_ws.FluidraWS port = service.getFluidraWSSOAP();
    port.getPriceLine(cono, faci, cuno, itno, whlo, ordt, orqa, alun, cucd,
    ortp, prrf, disy, dwdt, cfxx, cama, atnr, pltb, cfin, sapr, lnam, orqs, 
    smcd, aagn, bagn, prmo, spun, sacd, prro, cmno, dia1, dia2, dia3, dia4, 
    dia5, dia6, dic1, dic2, dic3, dic4, dic5, dic6, cmp1, cmp2, cmp3, cmp4, 
    cmp5, cmp6, tx81, tx82, tx83, tx84, tx85, tx86, chl1, chl2, chl3, chl4, 
    chl5, chl6, sac2, tinc, ntcd, dip1, dip2, dip3, dip4, dip5, dip6, sap1, 
    sap2, sap3, sap4, sap5, sap6, dpr1, dpr2, dpr3, dpr4, dpr5, dpr6, netp, 
    odam);
}
```

On the contrary if I try to invoke the webservice using soapui I can see the input and output object.

How can I generate client where the operation has output object as result and input object as parameter?

Comment: May you want to take a look at similar question answere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344961/given-a-wsdl-file-create-a-simple-java-client