# Web service client from local WSDL file

Tags: java, wsdl

How can I generate web service client from local WSDL file in java? I do not have wsdl URL.

Comment: Use a `file:` URL: wsimport -p com.example.service -d projectdir/build/generated-classes file:///home/manoj/someservice.wsdl

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344961/given-a-wsdl-file-create-a-simple-java-client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate java classes from WSDL file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920175/how-to-generate-java-classes-from-wsdl-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web service client given WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172118/web-service-client-given-wsdl)